# Валидация формы, где ошибка?

Tags: javascript

Доброго времени суток,
Делаю валидацию формы, подскажите где ошибка? не отрабатывает блок if/else

```
submitForm: function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var form = $(this),
                submitBtn = form.find('button[type="submit"]');
            console.log(app.validateform(form));
            if( app.validateform(form) === false ) {
              alert('false');
              return false;
            }else {
              alert('ajax next');
            }

          },
```

При любом значении true/false срабатывает только else..
Хотя app.validateform(form) возвращает именно true/false
Ссылка на код и форму: [JSfidle](https://jsfiddle.net/a7544zxs/2/)

Просьба помочь. Спасибо.

Comment: `app.validateform(form) === 'false'`. Ваш validateform возвращает и не true и не false, а вполне себе строки.

Comment: Понял, когда объявлял переменную зачем-то поставил кавычки.  Спасибо